# Gamma identity confusion

Tags: complex-analysis

Why does it make sense to talk about the identity $\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$ $\forall z$

when at $z=0,-1,-2$ the above identity implies that the gamma function is not defined at these points? I understand how to show this identity is true except when $z=0, -1, -2 ...$ by analytic continuation but my notes suggest it can be extended to all $z$.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense, because both sides are undefined for those values, so claiming that they are equal doesn't give any problems, and it's easier to say that the formula holds on $\mathbb C$ than on $\mathbb C\setminus\{-n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$, but it means the same.

Comment: The two sides are also equal _as meromorphic functions_.